# C program initialize flash memory and detect it was initialized

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller, low-level, flash-memory

I want to save some values in external flash memory to a microcontroller. These values are typically going to be incremented every time I run the program. I would like to initialize them to 0.
Before I can write to this memory I need to make sure it is initialized.
I want to do that by selecting a fixed location in memory that indicates whether or not it is initialized. In the beginning of the program, check whether it was previously initialized, if not, do the initialization and then proceed with reads and writes.

Is there a better way?

work in progress. I will try this, looking for a better approach if possible

Comment: What does "initialized" mean in this context?  You want your software to detect if this is the very first boot of the system?  (Or if the flash has been erased since last boot?)  IIRC, Flash normally reads as all-one bits (-1 = 0xFFFFFFFF) on erase.  If you have a byte somewhere that you write to 0 before you start writing anything else, and then write it (or another byte) to 1 after writing everything else, you can detect that everything's already initialized successfully, or that init started but didn't finish (e.g. power loss or failed flash), or that flash is freshly erased.

Comment: Is this NAND flash with your own wear-leveling, such that you can only write by erasing a large block?  Or does it support byte or word stores?

Comment: some flash technology we see the erased state as zero and you write ones, but traditionally erased is one and you can only write zeros (you cant go from 0 back to a 1 on a bit without erasing a whole block)

Comment: you have to experimentally determine the erased state as all ones or all zeros and you determine erased that way using that state.  then you can choose how to consume the flash, you can do it per page and write a new page, maybe use a counter as indicated, and scan all the pages to find the largest and find erased ones and then choose the next erased one in a circular manner write with the next count.  making sure you erase one/some at some point.  sounds though you are going to wear out the flash prematurely

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this in any other way than reading the friendly datasheet of the particular external flash memory and see which is the erased state (most commonly all ones). And then checking if it is initialized is simply about checking if the memory cell hold a value different than the erased state.

Comment: @PeterCordes essentially yes by initialize I mean detect the first boot of the system (after my changes) Its a NOR flash

Answer (score 0):

Initializing flash to 0 (and frequently modifying flash contents) is generally problematic if you want to modify it later because usually the flash controller in micros can only write from a 1 -> 0, and the "erased" state is all 1's.

You can read-erase-write to the flash every time, but this is also somewhat problematic because usually the flash controller can only erase an entire page at a time.  So you'll need to read and write back everything you care about on the entire page...  If that's acceptable it should work though.  Just make sure you've offset your application code correctly so you don't accidentally erase it as well.

Some flash controllers on't support modifying flash while running from flash, and require you to execute out of RAM when modifying the flash contents.  That could be another complication to consider.

I can't think of any great alternatives for this unless you're willing to go off-chip to an external EEPROM.

Comment: "values in external flash memory" They seem to already be off-chip.

Comment: @Lundin I should have added it clearly in my question, this is an off-chip external EEPROM. I understand I will have to erase before writing.

Comment: @ugh Is it flash or EEPROM? Flash, you can only erase it so many times (10,000 - 100,000) before it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a struct to contain the related values that you want to save in nonvolatile memory.  Putting the data in a struct makes it easy to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data for reading and writing to nonvolatile memory.

Furthermore, the struct technique allows you to add a versioning parameter to the struct.  It's helpful to version the struct so that future versions of the firmware can add features to the struct while remaining backwards compatible with previous versions of the struct (which may be saved in the nonvolatile memory of units out in the field).  That is, the new firmware will read the struct version from the saved data and then know how to interpret both the old and new versions of the data.

And finally, the struct technique allows you to add a validation parameter to the struct.  I typically add a CRC parameter to the end of the struct.  The CRC value is calculated over all the other data bytes in the struct when the struct is saved.  And then the CRC value is checked when the struct is read from nonvolatile memory.  This ensures that the data read from nonvolatile memory is valid.  And it also provides a way to determine whether the saved data is uninitialized.  For example, when the firmware reads the data from blank nonvolatile memory then the CRC check will fail and this indicates that the saved data is uninitialized.

```
struct my_saved_data {
  uint32_t version;       // The version of this struct (for backwards compatibility)
  uint32_t data_value_1;
  uint16_t data_value_2;
  uint16_t data_value_3;
  uint16_t crc;           // The CRC value of the preceding data (for validation and uninitialized check)
} my_saved_data;
```